# Check whether React application is running in a Docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

For Node servers I am able to figure out whether they are running in a Docker container using the [`is-docker`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-docker) package. This obviously doesn't work for React applications which run in the browser rather than the command line which makes `fs` unavailable. Is there any other way to let a web application figure out whether it is running in a Docker container?

Comment: Browsers almost never run in Docker containers, so you can make a fairly strong assumption that your browser-based React app isn't running in a Docker container.  Why would it matter?

Comment: If you need the react app running in the browser know, then just pass the flag down or maybe query it via an HTTP req to the server

Comment: @DavidMaze My question is most likely ambiguous. Of course I am not running the actual browser in the Docker container, only the application which is served using play `serve` for the time being. When the user browses to the application the built code, which is executed in the users browser, no longer can easily acces infoamtion about the server it's running on. Especially when it comes down to recognizing whether the server is dockerized.

Comment: Just a minor addition: my motivation is that I am connecting to a GraphQL server an depending on whether this happens locally during development via `localhost` or in production in a multi-container setup with `docker-compose` I'd like the application to connected to the linked server (via `docker-compose`) rather than plain `localhost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that `create-react-app` [supports injecting environment variables](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) into `process.env` during build time using `.env` files. Thus I created a `.env.development` file which contains `REACT_APP_DOCKERENV=false` and a `.env.production` file which contains `REACT_APP_DOCKERENV=true`. Those variables are then injected when running `yarn start` and `yarn build` respectively.

Of course this assumes my development builds are always executed locally while the production builds are always executed in Docker which works in my particular scenario.